# MySQLDump to local machine from remote server where remote server is bound to localhost

Tags: mysql, ssh

Is there a way of dumping a database from a remote server where the remote server is bound to localhost.  My only thought is to use a ssh tunnel to port forward 3306.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks

I've tried:

`mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> -h <remote machine> <table> > dump.dmp`

I get back:

`mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<remote machine>:3306' (111) when trying to connect`

Comment: most likely not possible because of firewall configuration on remote servers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ssh user@remote_host "mysqldump -u Usue -p'pass' DB | gzip -9" > localPath/dblocal.sql.gz
```